# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un valor que seleccionó el usuario desde un iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

El tema es que tengo este `iframe`:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.megatravel.com.mx/tools/vi.php?
    Dest=7&txtColor=333333&aColor=333333&ahColor=FF6600&
    thBG=28B1DF&thTxColor=333333&ff=9"
    width="800" height="1200" border="0"
    align="left" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
```

Y es una lista de destinos que puede seleccionar el usuario.

Lo que quiero hacer es obtener ese valor que el usuario seleccionó para poder generar un formulario basado en la selección.

En la página para entregarlo solo explican esto:

Opciones de formato `iframe` destinos:

- Al `iframe` se le pueden asignar variables que permiten personalizar los colores del contenido y tipografía del diseño.
- Personaliza el enlace para que se adecue al diseño de tu página web.
- Debes enviar valores por la URL.

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Dónde exactamente el usuario selecciona eso? ¿Cuál es el código que estás implementando para lograrlo? ¿Qué problemas o errores tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.